# Run a Google Sheets script on all tabs except one

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-workspace-for-business

Thanks in advance for the help. I am currently running a Google Sheets script which applies to one tab called "Tab 1". It copies a range across to the next free column as follows:

```
function copyAcross() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var namesSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Tab 1')
  var names = namesSheet.getRange('A9:A12').getValues().filter(function (r) {return r[0]})
  namesSheet.getRange(9, namesSheet.getLastColumn() +1, names.length, 1).setValues(names)
}
```

I would like this script to run on ALL tabs EXCEPT one tab called "Targets".

Here is an example of the Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MUFR7XjSxiu_fe86fZjdQrm1fPjMLBvi8rxw3HkvKbs/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to loop over the sheets and use some criteria to decide whether to do the copy on a given sheet. Perhaps it would be easiest to use a regular expression to match sheet names, like this:

```
function copyToFirstFreeColumn() {
  const sheetRegex = /^(Tab \d)/i;
  const rangeA1 = 'A9:A12';
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()
    .forEach(sheet => {
      if (!sheet.getName().match(sheetRegex)) {
        return;
      }
      const currentRange = sheet.getRange(rangeA1);
      currentRange
        .offset(0, sheet.getLastColumn() - currentRange.getColumn() + 1)
        .setValues(currentRange.getValues());
    });
}
```

See https://regexone.com/ and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) for more info.

Comment: This is really helpful, thanks. One tweak - I notice that this loop applies the function to any tab with "Tab" in the name. I will be adding other tabs, so is there a way to apply the function on all tabs EXCEPT certain ones (called "Targets" and "Markbook")?

Comment: Try something like `if (sheet.getName().match(/^(Targets|Markbook)$/i))`. See the regex references I gave for more info.

Comment: Sorted - thanks very much!